# How to make Wartremover's compiler plug-in v0.13 compatible to Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

When I add the linting tool Wartremover as an SBT plug-in by listing it in the file `.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugin.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.brianmckenna" % "sbt-wartremover" % "0.13")
```

Eclipse Mars complains with the following error shown in the Problems view:

```
Compiler plugin wartremover_2.11-0.13.jar is cross-compiled with incompatible version for this project: 2.11.0 vs 2.11.7
```

How can I solve this problem so that the error above permanently disappears?

In my `build.sbt` file I configured Wartremover like:

```
wartremoverErrors ++= Warts.unsafe filterNot { _ == Wart.DefaultArguments }
```